# Reshaping of 1d-array into list of 2d-arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 1d-data stream with a length of `M`, concatenating `N` channels, which I would like to feed to a processing function (i.e. having a total length of `M*N`. This processing function expects data split into channels, and with a slice size of `K`, with `K` smaller or equal than `M`, i.e. corresponding to a 2d-array with a shape of `[N, K]`.

My current approach to reshape my input data from 1d into a list of 2d-arrays (i.e. effectively a 3d-array) is the following:

```
# Generation of test data with a shape of N*M as 1d-array
data_list:list[float] = []
for channel_no in range(N):
    data_list.extend(
        (np.arange(M) + 10 * M * channel_no).tolist()
    )

# Reshaping of 1d-array into 2d-arrays, effectively splitting 
# the data into N channels
in_data: np.ndarray = np.asarray(data_list).reshape(
    N, M
)

# Generating list of 2d-arrays with shape [N, K] and a length of M // K
target_data: np.ndarray = reshape_numpy_array_with_equal_blocks(
    in_array=in_data,
    target_shape=(N, K),
    drop_last=True,
    use_padding=True,
)
```

with the corresponding function `reshape_numpy_array_with_equal_blocks()`:

```
def reshape_numpy_array_with_equal_blocks(
    in_array: np.ndarray,
    target_shape: Tuple[int, int],
    use_padding: bool = False,
    drop_last: bool = True,
    padding_val: float = 0.0,
) -> np.ndarray:
    """_summary_

    Args:
        in_array (np.ndarray): _description_
        target_shape (Tuple[int, int]): _description_
        use_padding (bool, optional): _description_. Defaults to False.
        drop_last (bool, optional): _description_. Defaults to True.
        padding_val (float, optional): _description_. Defaults to 0.0.

    Raises:
        NotImplementedError: _description_

    Returns:
        np.ndarray: _description_
    """
    in_array_shape = in_array.shape
    if len(in_array_shape) != 2:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    ret_array = []
    for i in range(0, in_array_shape[-1], target_shape[-1]):
        channel_array = []
        if i + target_shape[-1] <= in_array_shape[-1]:
            for channel in range(in_array_shape[0]):
                channel_array.append(
                    in_array[channel, i : i + target_shape[-1]].tolist()
                )
            ret_array.append(channel_array[:])
        else:
            if not drop_last and use_padding:
                for channel in range(in_array_shape[0]):
                    cur_data = in_array[channel, i:].tolist()
                    cur_data_len = len(cur_data)
                    cur_data.extend([padding_val] * (target_shape[-1] - cur_data_len))
                    channel_array.append(cur_data[:])
                ret_array.append(channel_array[:])
    return np.array(ret_array)
```

However, I'm not sure if this approach is the most efficient version, as it contains quite a bit re-allocation and copying of memory. What would be a better approach?

I was thinking of using a generator which accesses sliced parts of the original data list, such that no additional allocations/copies are necessary, but I'm not sure if that is the way to go either. Would that be a viable solution, or are there even better approaches? Or can this problem be circumvented completely?

Comment: What are some representative values for `N`, `M`, and `K`?

Comment: Typical values for `N` are between 3-6, `M` are in the order 1e5-1e9 and `K` in the range of 1e3-1e4, if that helps @jared?

Comment: I tested with `N=3`, `M=int(1e5)`, and `K=int(1e3)` and my code produced the same result as yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, and `M` is always divisible by `K`, then you can split the `in_data` array into sections with `M//K` columns using `np.split` and then combine them using `np.stack`.

```py
target_data = np.stack(np.split(in_data, M//K, 1))
```

If `M` will not always be divisible by `K`, then it looks like your code just drops the number of columns equal to the remainder of `M/K`.

```py
target_data = np.stack(np.split(in_data[:,:None if not M%K else -(M%K)], M//K, 1))
```

And, as hinted to by @[hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) in the comments, this can also be done using `reshape`s and `transpose`s.

```py
target_data = np.transpose(in_data[:,:None if not M%K else -(M%K)].T.reshape(M//K,K,N), (0,2,1))
```

In terms of speed, I tested using N=20, M=10, and K=2.

- OP's method: 62.7 µs ± 3.92 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
- `split`/`stack`: 28.9 µs ± 184 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
- `reshape`/`transpose`: 2.37 µs ± 73.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

Comment: I haven't followed what this OP want, but often when I see a `splt/stack` sequence, it seems that a `reshape/transpose/reshape` sequence is just as good, if not faster.  It still requires a copy.

Comment: @hpaulj See my updated answer. I was able to get the same results using `reshape`/`transpose` and it is indeed faster. Thanks for the suggestion.